# How to return a JSON result from inside using(){} block

Tags: c#, .net, generics, blazor

My code looks like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using TestApp.Model.StudentModel; 

namespace TestApp.Services
{

    public class TodoService
    {

        public string TodoURL { get; set; } = "https://******.***/api/student";
        StudentModel result; 

        public async Task<List<string>> GetTodoTypesAsync()
        {

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // accept respose as json
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")
                );

                // provide token with the request
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                    "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
                        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", "*****"
                        )
                    )
                );

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(TodoURL).Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StudentModel>(responseData);
                return result; 

            }

        }

    }
    
}
```

But I get the following error when I run the app:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'TestApp.Model.StudentModel.StudentModel' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' TestApp C:***\TestApp\Services\TodoService.cs   36  Active

It does not matter if I change

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetTodoTypesAsync()
```

to

```
public async Task<List<StudentModel>> GetTodoTypesAsync()
```

And this is a portion of the model StudentModel

```
namespace TestApp.Model.StudentModel
{
    public class Avatar
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudentModel
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related but please do not wrap the `HttpClient` into a `using` block rather reuse it multiple time against the same domain.

Comment: You really should inject that HttpClient.

Comment: This is my first C# project, I don't know how to do things the best way ... for now. I found a code that worked and just copy/pasted as I am trying to get the app to work

Comment: `public async Task<StudentModel> GetTodoTypesAsync()` otherwise different types in method signature and return statement

Comment: @Renat I tried that already and it doesn't work

Comment: @Blindy He said he is a beginner. We all learn by failing, don't we? OP: I suggest you make yourself familiar with [Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) ;D <- That whole blog is liquid gold ...

Comment: Thanks @Fildor I will read it tonight

Comment: _Probably_ unrelated, but class `StudentModel` is in a namespace called `StudentModel`. If I remember correctly, I had issues with that in the past ( namespace containing class of same name).

Comment: @Fidor, we can learn by failing, sure, but that's a lot of corpses if that's how doctors learned, for example. Sometimes pointing out mistakes, as well as why they are mistakes, hurries the whole process along.

Comment: @Fildor Someone made the same observation last time but didn't find any solutions, are they not to supposed to share the same name?

Comment: @Blindy Your comment was incredibly rude. You were right to point out OP’s mistake, but your tone was really disrespectful. When doctors attend medical school they don’t get slapped whenever they fail a test.

Comment: You must have not watched House. And you don't know my tone, you're just assuming it (and probably projecting).

Comment: @Blindy Well, two fellow users perceived your writing to be - let's say - "not on the welcoming side". I wouldn't go so far to call it rude, but you could have added some help instead of calling his work a load of crap, basically. No offense. Let's just be nice to each other. Maybe you _are_  just the "tough love" type? ;) haha

Comment: @vaeon 1) change to `Task<List<StudentModel>> GetTodoTypesAsync()`  2) change to `List<StudentModel> result;` 3) change to `result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StudentModel>>(responseData);` 4)missing a close parenthesis `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue` . IMHO - make it work, then optimize later. Your code is def not production ready, so do heed the above comments about `HttpClient` and def read Stephen Clearly blog

Comment: @thewallrus Thanks a lot, I will try it shortly

Comment: _"are they not to supposed to share the same name?"_ - to be honest, I forgot what the details of the result of my research were. All I remember is "don't do. Is bad bad." I am sure there is a reason for that and I don't know if the issue is gone in newer versions. I really should take better notes of that kind of stuff. :) I am pretty sure I solved the issue by renaming either namespace or class. But again: not even sure if that's an issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should supply an example of the JSON but anyways...

You are deserializing your response to StudentModel, implying that your responsedata contains a single StudentModel.

If your responsedata is an Array you should Deserialize it as StudentModel[] or List.

If responsedata contains a single StudentModel then your method needs to return StudentModel not List